# Compare/Calculate like files

Tags: bash, grep

I have program generating reports on a regular basis.
These reports are follow a simple and consistent format (specifically, these are "OProfile profiling reports).
Each line's format is:

- Unique_name,number

I wish to run over all the reports I have and calculate (say) and average for each unique_name.

How could this be done?

Comment: Just to make sure you are not reinventing the wheel: you are aware of `opreport` command, right?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the reports located in a directory and have the `.txt` extension. Try this:

```
$ cat *.txt | gawk -F, 'NF==2 { sum[$1] += $2; N[$1]++ } \
    END { for (name in sum) { \
        printf "%s %f\n", name, sum[name] / N[name]; } }' | sort -k2 -n
```